# Изменить url для логина

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Создаю приложение используя стандартный шаблон "Веб-приложение ASP.NET Core" - "Веб-приложение (модель-представление-контроллер)" - ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Аутентификация без проверки подлинности

Добавляю все необходимые библиотеки из NuGet

Создаю модель пользователя

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{ 
    //
}
```

Контекст

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Изменяю файл Startup.cs, где собственно пытаюсь задать путь вида `"/Account/Register"`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Register");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Register");

        });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Соответственно создаю контролер и необходимые методы. Метод Index контролера Home помечаю атрибутом [Authorize]. Но при запуске приложения получаю следующее сообщение:

> Страница localhost не найдена Не найдена страница для веб-адреса
>   https://localhost:44304/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F HTTP ERROR 404

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А если добавить в `AddIdentity`  - `.AddDefaultUI()`?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ничего не изменилось